# How to predict a specific row in a column using a prediction model python?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, data-science, prediction

I have the following code which works :

```
for model in models:
    model.fit(trainset)
    predictions = model.test(testset)
    top_n = get_top_n(predictions, n=5)

    # Print the first one
    user = list(top_n.keys())[0]
    print(f'model: {model}, {user}: {top_n[user]}')
print('Top N computation successful!')
```

But the challenge is this - I am trying to use the model to predict football games. The two columns of interest are : `home_game` and `away_game`.

And the two items of interest in those columns are : `Chelsea` and `West Ham`.

How is the best way to conditionally select these two items using the model described above?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your dataframe looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'home_game':['Man Utd', 'Chelsea', 'Arsenal'], 'away_game':['Liverpool','West Ham','Spurs']})

    away_game   home_game
0   Liverpool   Man Utd
1   West Ham    Chelsea
2   Spurs       Arsenal
```

you can select the row with Chelsea and West Ham this way:

```
test = df[(df['home_game'] == 'Chelsea') & (df['away_game'] == 'West Ham')]
```

and predict this by passing the resulting dataframe (depending on your models prediction function):

```
model.predict(test)
```

Comment: Ok, let me try it out.

Comment: I just did and I got this `TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iid'`

Comment: Can you please update you example with your existing data frame and specific model trained?

Comment: `df.head()`
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/14vRQj1A1wqxQkL3sMd9wlVdTJUi08S5K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `# list of models`
    `models = [model_random, model_svd, model_svdpp, model_nmf,`
    `model_slopeone, model_knnbasic,` `model_knnwithmeans,model_knnbaseline,` 
    `model_coclustering, model_baselineonly, model_knnwithzscore, model_user,` 
    `model_item]`

Comment: what are you predicting and which other columns have been used in training? The number of columns used in training and prediction should be the same.\

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Guess that is what I have been trying to figure out.

Comment: So, what is the best way to re-write this?